# Create Toast from different thread that implements looper

Tags: android, multithreading

Can i create a toast from different thread that implements a looper or using HandlerThread.It is compulsory to create toast or any ui operation using main looper.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, a Toast can be invoked only on the main thread. If you want to throw a Toast from a different thread, you have to rout it to the main thread.

You can do that by:

1. Using the "runOnUiThread" method from an Activity:

   ```
   activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           Toast.makeText(context, "Hello, world!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
   });
   ```
2. Posting a runnable with the Toast invocation to a Handler that is
   running on the main thread looper:

   ```
   private Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
       handler.post(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               Toast.makeText(context, "Hello, world!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
       });
   ```